# How to highlight down columns for many columns at once that are separated in an excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, shortcuts, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have 30 columns of data with over 10,000 rows. I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> to highlight specific cells and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down arrow</kbd> to highlight to the bottom, but I noticed it won't let me do that whenever I have multiple cells highlighted (see photo). How can I do this? I just want to be able to highlight certain subsets of the data and graph them in this large datasheet quickly. Any suggestions for this?

[image: Columns I want to drag down to the bottom with]

Answer (score 0):

Try to select each Column cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> but not select all Columns cells directly:

1. Select Cell A6 and Ctrl+Shift+Down
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click Cell C6 and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click Cell E6 and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click Cell F6 and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

[image]